# Why my text box's border color doesn't grow?

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox as follow.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwordr">Repeat Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" required="" name="passwordr" value="">
                    <span class="help-block">Type the password again. Passwords must match.</span>


  </div>
```

I am expecting to have a textbox with a glowing colour when the user click the textbox.

But it doesn't happen now.
Please see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_nyan/apeqjdth/1/).

I have another setting, it works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_nyan/sLeLp12w/1/).

I think pretty much the same.

The second one has rounded corner and the light grows.
Why the first one doesn't have rounded corner and the light doesn't glow?

EDIT:

[image: img]

Comment: Neither of the examples you linked to have inputs with rounded corners.

Comment: @AndyRay, my browser can see the difference. One has straight corner. The other one is a bit rounded. Let me check from another pc.

Comment: @AndyRay Do you notice that one has growing color and the other one doesn't have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!imporant` for apply `css` forcefully and effects same as bootstrap.

```
.form-control:focus{ 
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1) !important;
   border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1) !important;

}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/apeqjdth/6)

Comment: I have EDIT added. I don't mean that color. When the user click the textbox, the lightblue color blows. I think that is from Bootstrap. I have two pages. Register page has that effect. But Login page doesn't have. I wonder why. Somehow, it doesn't happen exact in JSFiddle.

Comment: yeah sort of. But the colour does not have glow effect. I mean some shading effect. Just constant border line happens. What I want is with glow effect.

Comment: wait i'll add box shadow or you add your own ;)

Comment: I use the same code on my page. The second one has all those effect. But the first one does not have. I wonder why. The code I used are same as shown in the Fiddles.  I wonder why the first one doesn't have glow effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105417/discussion-between-gautam-jha-and-batuman).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an input to have a different/special appearance once selected, use the :focus CSS pseudo-class.

A simple example:

```
#myInput:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

PS. I assume you mean "glow", not "grow", and certainly not "blow" :-)

Comment: I have EDIT added. I don't mean that color. When the user click the textbox, the lightblue color blows. I think that is from Bootstrap. I have two pages. Register page has that effect. But Login page doesn't have. I wonder why. Somehow, it doesn't happen exact in JSFiddle.

Comment: sorry yes it is glow.